# Allowing numbers ending in 5 and 0 only

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation

I'm looking for a form validation script (presumably JavaScript?).

We want this to be an input text field, not a drop down. The company provides a product which is custom cut at various lengths. The minimum order is 0.5m and after that they are only want to allow lengths in increments of `0.05m`, like this:

ONLY ALLOW numbers where, if present, the two decimal points end in a `0` or `5`.

> - 0.50 (minimum order)
> - 0.55
> - 0.60
> - 0.65
> - etc...
> - 1.00
> - 1.05
> - 1.10
> - 1.15
> - etc...
> - 130.00
> - 130.05
> - 130.10
> - etc...

Any thoughts? Suggestions?

Update:

I realised that the solution needs to be incorporated in to some existing script, which might either complicate or simplify the situation? Here is the code that handles the actions upon the form submission.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

  $('select[name="profile_id"], input[name="quantity"]').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=product/product/getRecurringDescription',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('input[name="product_id"], input[name="quantity"], select[name="profile_id"]'),
    dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#profile-description').html('');
        },
    success: function(json) {
        $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

        if (json['success']) {
                $('#profile-description').html(json['success']);
        }   
    }
  });
  });

  $('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

        if (json['error']) {
            if (json['error']['option']) {
                for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                    $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                }
            }

                if (json['error']['profile']) {
                    $('select[name="profile_id"]').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['profile'] + '</span>');
                }
        } 

        if (json['success']) {
            $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

            $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

            $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
        }   
    }
  });
  });
  //--></script>
```

Comment: Try searching for character classes.  And anchors too.  And a tutorial on regex too.

Comment: [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/lY0qT2)

Comment: are the numbers floats or strings? this is very important for the approach ...

Comment: 0.00 will satisfy moob

Comment: Someone suggested to me that you could use a round-up function? So if a user types in 1.03 it would round to 1.05 equally if they typed in 1.17 it would round to 1.20 - thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function. This checks if the value is above or equal to 0.5 and if the value is a multiply of 0.05 :

```
function check(value) {
    var val = value * 1000;
    var ok = (val>=500) && (val % 50 == 0);
    console.log(value, ok);
    return ok;
}
check(0.50);
check(0.55);
check(0.60);
check(0.65);
check(0.51);
check(0.157);
check(0.64);
check(0.1165);
```

outputs

```
0.5 true
0.55 true
0.6 true
0.65 true
0.51 false
0.157 false
0.64 false
0.1165 false
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm very much a Javascript newbie unfortunately - could you show me how to incorporate that logic in to checking the input of a text field when the user clicks a submit?

Comment: @SomeGuy, see this demo -> http://jsfiddle.net/QTW6N/, an input field (length) and a submit button, alerting if the entered value is acceptable or not.

Comment: thanks for that, I really appreciate it. The only snag I've hit is on the checkout page. This lists all the products in the user's basket along with their quantities, which the user can edit from this page. Each quantity box  has the ID "quantity[<?php echo $product['key']; ?>]" - i.e. unique. Is there anyway to check all the quantity* boxes on a page or should I post this as a fresh question?

Comment: I've updated my original question to show the code that works on the individual product pages. Does that complicate or ease the integration of the function you suggested?

Comment: This one worked with a bit of additional help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can mod out by a decimal in JS. You'll want to use a function to test "equality" of the numbers, since they're floats.

```
function validate(num){
    return approximatelyEqual(num % 0.05, 0);
}

function approximatelyEqual(x, y){
    return Math.abs(x - y) < 0.00000001;
}
```

(This is assuming that you have already converted the input to a number.)

Comment: Any idea if that could be combined with the code I updated my original question with?

Comment: Yes, it could be used with anything... If you don't see how this could be used, perhaps you should post a different question outlining the problem you're having. SO isn't meant to be a "do my programming for me" kind of site, though if that's what you're looking for there are certainly forums on the internet that will walk you through a project step-by-step.

Comment: Just from a cursory look at the code you provided, it doesn't seem there is any opportunity for the user to input improper numbers. I see what looks like a button and a select statement, but no input box. So why are you trying to validate the data in the first place? Perhaps you could explain a little more about what the components of this project are and then it would be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

A regexp that matches your particular numbers is this one:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d?[05])?$
```

DEMO: http://regex101.com/r/yO6eO2

It is not a very good check, as it allows numbers to start with 0 for example. If that bothers you, you can easily fix it by looking at other number regexps.

Here is a demo integrating the solution in JavaScript:

http://jsbin.com/wutizuri/1

It should do nothing on submit for bad entries and go to /valid when the input contains a valid number.

Code: http://jsbin.com/wutizuri/1/edit

Comment: The minimum order is 0.5 so therefore you would need to allow a number starting with 0 anyway? With the regex, can you incorporate that in to a Javascript check on a text field when they click submit?

Comment: I meant that 000.60 is matched by the regexp. Of course you can use it to validate the value in the text field on submit. I will add an example.

Comment: On the checkout/cart page it shows all the products in their basket with the quantities next to each one. Each quantity is in an input field and has a different ID (handled by quantity[<?php echo $product['key']; ?>]) this allows users to update their quantities without having to return to each product page. Will your JS example check all input fields or could it some how?

Answer (score 0):

The character class `[05]` matches a digit that is `0` or `5`.
`[0-9]` matches a digit from 0 to 9
`\.` matches a dot.

Combining all, you have your regex:

```
^[0-9]+\.[0-9][05]$
```

The next one take into account that the min value is `0.50`.

```
^(?:0\.[5-9]|[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9])[05]$
```

Answer (score 0):

If catering only for browsers that support HTML5 then you could do something like this.

HTML

```
<form>
    <input id="cutLength" type="number" min="0.5" step="0.05" value="0.5" required></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('cutLength').addEventListener('invalid', function () {
    if (this.validity.rangeUnderflow) {
        this.setCustomValidity("Minimum order of 0.5m");
    } else if (this.validity.stepMismatch) {
        this.setCustomValidity("Order must be in steps of 0.05m");
    } else if (this.validity.typeMismatch || this.validity.valueMissing) {
        this.setCustomValidity("Please enter a number for the length");
    }
}, false);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/L36eq/)

If you want to do a little reading on the subject then this is a fairly good article. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/

It points to available polyfills towards the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately we need to support as many browsers as possible in this instance.

Comment: That's what the polyfills are for. One of them mentioned is [Webshim](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html) but there are others.